# Writing unit tests which may access private/protectedstate

Tags: c++, testing, googletest, boost-test, gunit

I use Boost Test for unit tests. I typically have a fixture struct:

```
class ClassBeingTested
{
protected:
    int _x;             // Want to access this directly in my unit tests
};

struct TestFixture : public ClassBeingTested
{
    // I can access ClassBeingTested::_x here but it means i have to add getters for each test to call
    ClassBeingTested _bla;
};
```

However, even if my fixture inherits from `ClassBeingTested` or uses a friend relationship I cannot access private/protected methods/state from each individual test:

```
BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE(test1, TestFixture)
{
    _bla.doSomething();
    BOOST_REQUIRE_EQUAL(_bla.x, 10);    // Compiler error. I cannot access ClassBeingTested::_x here
}
```

only the fixture, which means I have to add a new getter (or test) for each access I wish to make.

Is there any way to achieve this? I have to add public getter methods to `ClassBeingTested` which are only used by tests, which isn't ideal.

(Please no replies of 'test using the public interface', that's not always possible).

Comment: You can make a friend test buddy, `struct ClassBeingTestedBuddy;` with `friend struct ClassBeingTestedBuddy;` in the class, and have the test buddy class expose all the protected or private variables or methods that you need for all your tests.  It'd look like `struct ClassBeingTestedBuddy { ClassBeingTested* obj; ClassBeingTestedBuddy(ClassBeingTested* obj_) : obj{obj_} {} };` plus anything you'd want to expose.

Comment: @Eljay hey, can you put this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a friend test buddy, `struct ClassBeingTestedBuddy;` with `friend struct ClassBeingTestedBuddy;` in the `class ClassBeingTested`.

Have the test buddy class expose all the protected or private variables or methods that you need for all your tests.

It'd look like...

```
struct ClassBeingTestedBuddy {
    ClassBeingTested* obj;
    ClassBeingTestedBuddy(ClassBeingTested* obj_)
      : obj{obj_} {}
};
```

...plus anything else you'd want to expose.

This is but one way of allowing the tests a bridge to the protected and private data and methods.  But since it is all code in your project, for your testing use, it is a reasonable way of getting the test code access without too much instrumenting your actual code.